# How can I make a fluid text input using react, which resizes based on the content?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I'm trying to achieve this functionality:
https://paper.fiftythree.com/search

The input box should expand till a max-width based on the content inside.
I'm using React by Facebook to do this via state so render gets called automatically.

I've put together a small fiddle using span - but couldn't take it through:
http://jsfiddle.net/abhinavsingi/3az621c2/

```
var Hello = React.createClass({
                getInitialState: function(){
                    return {
                      name: 'hello'
                    };
                },
                render: function() {
                    return (
                        <div className="cont">
                           <span className="spacer-wrap">
                              <span className="spacer">{this.state.name}</span>
                           </span>
                           <input ref='name' id="nm-inp" className="input-wrap" value={this.state.name} onChange={this.onInputChange}/>
                       </div>
                    );
                },

              onInputChange: function(e){
                   console.log(e);
                   this.setState({name: e.currentTarget.value})
              }
           });      React.render(<Hello name="World" />, document.body);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using style;

```
    render: function() {
            var nameWidth = this.state.name.length + 'em';
            var spacerSty = {width: nameWidth};
            return (
                    <div className="cont">
                         <span className="spacer-wrap">
                                <span className="spacer" style={spacerSty}>{this.state.name}</span>
                         </span>
                         <input ref='name' id="nm-inp" className="input-wrap" value={this.state.name} onChange={this.onInputChange}/>
                 </div>
            );
    },
```